# ImportError after successful pip install

Tags: python, django, pip, installation

1. I install some lib in docker
   pip3.4 install 
   after installation I received the message `Successfully installed <lib>`
2. I checked install by `pip3.4 list` and  was in list
3. I write code in setting

   ```
   MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += (<lib>,)
   INSTALLED_APPS += (<lib>,)
   ```
4. Runserver in Pycharm and I got MSG

   ```
   Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f1b69b9b400>
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper fn(*args, **kwargs)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run autoreload.raise_last_exception()
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception six.reraise(*_exception)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise raise value.with_traceback(tb)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper fn(*args, **kwargs)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create module = import_module(entry)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   ImportError: No module named 'silk'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

One of possible problem is that lib is installed into environment of interpreter `a` while PyCharm is using interpreter `b`.

Use `pip3.4 show [pkg_name]` to see the location of package and also make sure the project interpreter in PyCharm is the same.

Comment: thx for advice I checked location of package using `pip3.4 show [pkg_name]`

installed in `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages`

PyCharm interpreter is same

Comment: Then can you see desired package for current project? You should be able to see all installed packages there.

Comment: I can't see installed package in PyCharm project interpreter, so I try to add package in PyCharm but add button is disabled